# Sending an Internet request without prompting

Tags: java-me

In my application, I just want to upload some data on the server without interacting with the user.

How do I silently upload data on the server in J2ME without asking the user for Internet usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is impossible. All the phones ask the user before letting an application use internet services.

One possibility could be signing the application somehow, but that would work on very few phones, if any.

Answer (score 1):

In order to upload silently, the user must approve at least once that it allows you to connect to the internet, as specified by the [MIDP 2.0 Security Architecture](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/).

First you have to sign your Midlet with a certificate from a Certificate Authority (commonly refered as CAs) as Verisign, Thawte, Java Verified, etc. You have to choose your CA depending on the devices you are targeting. The device will just recognize the CAs installed as root certificates. If it doesn't have the root certificate of the CA you chose, it will not be a secure third-party application. This is explained in simple steps in the [Nokia Wiki](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Verisign_signing_-_Java_ME)

The second step is to set in your JAD file the next line

MIDlet-Permissions: javax.microedition.io.Connector.http

This will ask for http connections permission since it is installed.

In this way the user will just be noticed once, and will be allowed to set the permission permanently. Some devices will not allow a permanent permission if the application is not signed.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is signed by Java Verify or similar you will be able to let the user say they allow all future http connections, rather than having to authorise them all singularly.